# How to debug bazel analysis phase (and use remap_files with a bazel rules_pks pkg_tar rule)?

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

Using bazel 3.4 and rules_pkg 0.3. I have a directory of directories of so's, each sub-directory containing the .so's for a specific architecture and would like to tar up the .so for distribution. I want to strip the architecture directory so that the final pkg.tar will have one less folder in the hierarchy. (This will also make pointing the loader to the .so a bit easier). I'm using rules_pkg 0.3, so pkg_files is not available.

When I build the following rule, it appears remap_paths does absolutely nothing and I still see lib/arm64, lib/amd64 in my output tar. Am I missing something obvious?

Steps I've already taken:

I've inspected the arguments file to the action phase of tar_pkgs with `bazel build --subcommands target` and have confirmed that remap isn't being applied to the contents of the argument file. The issue must be in the analysis phase.

In attempting to debug in the analysis phase, I've put print statements in my local copy of rules_pkgs located at `~/.cache/sandox_hash/external/rules_pkg/pkg.bzl`, but this doesn't seem to do anything. Even if I put syntactically invalid python in pkg.bzl, the build will unaffected, so it seems this file isn't being reparsed.

What tools can I use to print/ debug in the analysis phase?
Thank you!

```
pkg_tar(
    name = "my_tar",
    srcs = select({
      "//condition_here" : ["lib/arm64"]
      "//conditions:default" : ["lib/amd64"]
    }),
    remap_paths = {
        "lib/amd64" : "lib",
        "lib/arm64" : "lib",
    }, 
    mode = "0644",
    package_dir = "/package/dir",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

2 issues with the above code:

1. Keys in remap paths need to be relative to the project workspace directory, not the package directory that contains the rule.
   For very obscure reasons on reading
2. On reading the source, it appears I need strip_prefix to be non-empty (e.g., `strip_prefix = "never_match_me"` in order to for remap_paths to parse correctly. I honestly don't understand the semantic intent of this, but that's how the code is written. https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_pkg/blob/36e8363/pkg/pkg.bzl

After making the above changes, this behaves as expected.

I'm still unclear why I'm not able to put print statements into my copy of the external repo rules_pkg in my ~/.cache/bazel to have debugged this. Still looking for an answer here, thanks!